# Calling JAVA methods in XML in the Eclips env

Tags: java, xml

Can any one tel me how to call JAVA method in XML and how to give class path? am using 1.0 xml processor and whether java class and xml file should keep separately in different package..? is there any materiel to read about this? can any one help me.........

Answer (score 2):

Using onClick attribute of a view you can call java methods from xml. The following xml sample code for button will demonstrate this.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Buy"
            android:onClick="upgradeToPremium"/>
```

and define that method in java

```
public void upgradeToPremium()
{
...
}
```